# Could you overflow the message queue of an Erlang process?

Tags: erlang

I'm still in the learning fase of Erlang, so I might be wrong, but this is how I understood a process' message queue.

A process could be in it's main receive loop, receiving certain types of messages, while later it could be put in a waiting loop to deal with a different kind of message in the second loop. If the process would receive messages intended for the first loop in the second loop, it would just put them in the queue, ignore them for the time being and only process those message that it can match against in the current loop it is in. Now if it would enter the first receive loop again, it would start from the beginning and again process the messages that it can match against.

Now my question would be, if this is how Erlang works and I understood this correctly, then what happens when a malicious process would send a bunch of messages that the process will never process. Will the queue eventually overflow, resulting in a crash for the process or how should I deal with this? I'll type out an example to illustrate what I mean.

Now if a malicious program would get a hold of the Pid and would go `Pid ! {malicioudata, LotsOfData}` repeatedly, would those messages be filtered out since they will never possibly be processed or would they just stack up in the queue?

```
startproc() -> firstloop(InitValues).

firstloop(Values) ->
  receive
    retrieveinformation ->
      WaitingList=askforinformation(),
      retrieveloop(WaitingList);
    dostuff ->
      NewValues=doingstuff(),
      firstloop(NewValues);
    sendmeyourdata ->
      sendingdata(Values),
      firstloop(Values)
  end.

retrieveloop([],Values) -> firstloop(Values).
retrieveloop(WaitingList,Values) ->
  receive
    {hereismyinformation,Id,MyInfo} ->
      NewValues=dosomethingwithinfo(Id,MyInfo),
      retrieveloop(lists:remove(Id,1,WaitingList),NewValues);
  end.
```

Comment: I guess that in the best scenario you would run out of memory. But my question is; how would a "malicious program" interact with erlang's PIDs, have the attacker sniffed your node's cookie? In that case, queue overflow is the least bad thing that could happen. In case of memory leak, If erlang crashes by a memory issue, then you could read the generated crash dump.

Comment: @Evalon In the vanilla case, Erlang is *assumed to be operating in a trusted environment by design*. There are other clustering methods which do not make this assumption, but they are add-ons, not vanilla Erlang runtime configurations. The assumption is that you directly control the cluster you're operating. Before you think "aw, that sucks" realize that *socket programming in Erlang is really easy*. So pretty much any meta-service of microservices you can imagine you can build with relative ease in Erlang, building clusters of clusters.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a hard limit on message counts, and there is not a fixed amount of memory you are limited to, but you can certainly run out of memory if you have billions of messages (or a few super huge ones, maybe).

Long before you OOM because of a huge mailbox you will notice either [selective receives taking a long time](http://thisotplife.tumblr.com/post/73303086711/when-a-selective-receive-is-taking-too-long) (not that "selective receive" is a good pattern to follow much of the time...) or innocently peek into a process mail queue and [realized you've opened Pandora's Box in your terminal](http://thisotplife.tumblr.com/post/52208880313/calling-process-info-1-on-a-process-with-a-huge).

This is usually treated as a throttling and monitoring issue in the Erlang world. If you aren't able to keep up and your problem is parallelizable then you need more workers. If you are maxing out your hardware then you need more efficiency. If you are still maxing out your hardware, can't get any more, and you're still overwhelmed then you need to decide how to implement pushback or load shedding.

Comment: @Evalon An excellent discussion of the subject. And with friendly pictures to break the discussion down to my level! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no "message queue overflow" and it's going to grow until VM crashes due to memory allocation error.

Solution is to drop any invalid messages in main loop, because you are not suppose to receive any of `{hereismyinformation, _,_}` nor one you get in `askforinformation()` due to blocking nature of your process.

```
startproc() -> firstloop(InitValues).

firstloop(Values) ->
  receive
    retrieveinformation ->
      WaitingList=askforinformation(),
      retrieveloop(WaitingList, Values); % i assume you meant that
    dostuff ->
      NewValues=doingstuff(),
      firstloop(NewValues);
    sendmeyourdata ->
      sendingdata(Values),
      firstloop(Values);
    _ -> 
      firstloop(Values) % you can't get {hereismyinformation, _,_} here so we can drop any invalid message
  end.

retrieveloop([],Values) -> firstloop(Values).
retrieveloop(WaitingList,Values) ->
  receive
    {hereismyinformation,Id,MyInfo} ->
      NewValues=dosomethingwithinfo(Id,MyInfo),
      retrieveloop(lists:remove(Id,1,WaitingList),NewValues);
  end.
```

It's not really a problem with unexpected messages because it's easily avoidable but when process queue is growing faster than it's processed. For this specific problem there is a nice [jobs framework](https://github.com/esl/jobs) for production systems.

Comment: The problem is, that when 'retrieveinformation' is received, it should ask for information, update its own values and only then start processing other messages again. So if someone would ask for the process' values, the process would first finish the update and only after it is finished send the new values. So should a third parameter be added with "RequestingStateList", and then when the state is updated, I will iterate that list, sending the current state or something?

Comment: @PeterRaeves i didn't get it. I did edit my answer. You need to add just one line to your code if you want to block it as you did and drop unexpected messages. Just thought you want it to be asynchronous also.

Comment: Hmm. It was that simple huh... That was indeed what I needed. And you are right, that I will not expect `hereismyinformation` messages in the first loop and if they were send, by an inexplicable reason, then they can safely be thrown away. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterRaeves no problem, it wasn't as much hard to guess ;)